LTSpice strange behavior using non-ideal capacitor in simulations
I've been trying to run some relatively simple simulations but am running into strange behavior, which I've narrowed down to using the non-ideal capacitor parameters in LTSpice (in both an old and an up to date version). This is what I'm running:

And this is the result I'm getting:

I don't understand what's happening at the 500MHz mark, why is the current suddenly increasing again?
Here's the contents of the LTSpice ASC file:
Version 4
SHEET 1 2036 680
WIRE 1232 -320 1152 -320
WIRE 1568 -320 1488 -320
WIRE 1568 -304 1568 -320
WIRE 1152 -208 1152 -320
WIRE 1232 -208 1232 -320
WIRE 1488 -208 1488 -320
WIRE 1568 -208 1568 -224
WIRE 1568 -112 1568 -144
WIRE 1152 -16 1152 -128
WIRE 1232 -16 1232 -144
WIRE 1488 -16 1488 -128
WIRE 1568 -16 1568 -32
FLAG 1152 -16 0
FLAG 1488 -16 0
FLAG 1568 -16 0
FLAG 1232 -16 0
SYMBOL Misc\\signal 1152 -224 M0
WINDOW 123 24 132 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL cap 1216 -208 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 10µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=10m Lser=10n
SYMBOL Misc\\signal 1488 -224 M0
WINDOW 123 24 132 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMBOL cap 1552 -208 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 10µ
SYMBOL res 1552 -320 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10m
SYMBOL ind 1552 -128 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 10n
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0
TEXT 1224 56 Left 2 !.ac dec 1000 1 10G


I think LTspice adds a nonzero parallel capacitance to capacitors when you set the series inductance to a nonzero value. If you set C1's parallel capacitance to 0, the second resonance should disappear.

Yes. This seems to be an LTspice thing- most other flavo[u]rs of SPICE just don't have the series inductance option (hence no need for a fix). Here, Mike Engelhardt explains why he didn't implement series inductance in QSPICE even though he did in LTspice.

Sneaky basterds! That does indeed fix it, and the commend from @Spehro'speff'Pefhany explains why. Very helpful, thank you to both of you. :)

@DavidKoster  If you get a chance, then please accept the answer as shown here:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235
